# moment.js not accepting "31\\Oct\\2016" as a date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Cant seem to figure why this works

```
moment("30\\Nov\\2016 22:14","DD\\MM\\YYYY HH:mm").toString()
```

(The result is `"Wed Nov 30 2016 22:14:00 GMT+0000"`)

and this does not work

```
moment("31\\Oct\\2016 22:14","DD\\MM\\YYYY HH:mm").toString()
```

(The result is `"Invalid date"`).

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

edit

changed the date above

edit 2

tried this snippet

`moment("30\\Jan\\2016 22:14","DD\\MMM\\YYYY HH:mm").toString()`

result = `"Wed Nov 30 2016 22:14:00 GMT+0000"`

thats strange

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't seem to work either -- `30\\Oct` should not map to `Nov 30`.

Comment: Look to the result, "Wed Nov", and november of 2016 doesn't has 31 days

Comment: Reading the docs it looks like you have to use dashes in the formatting portion (eg. don't use slashes or colon).

Comment: @DavidNguyen I don't see any evidence of that restriction. http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/ contains plenty of examples using slashes, and I've used it to parse dates with forward slashes plenty of times. Backslashes however, could be seen as escape sequences and might cause problems.

Comment: changed my first snippet to be the correct code for the first result.... got a little a head of myself typing!

Comment: but still the second result does not work and the first does work,

Comment: You have to use `MMM` instead of `MM` to parse months as Oct, Nov, etc, [see parsing  doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: that did not work, still same result

Comment: Looks like "\\" is used for formatting (`var formattingTokens = /(\[[^\[]*\])|(\\)?([Hh]mm(ss)?|Mo|MM?M?M?.../g`, [source](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/497f918515ae6ab900f008f19523b1e4ae5e2450/src/lib/format/format.js#L3)). If you double the backslashes and add a `M` the format string works -> `moment("31\\Oct\\2016 22:14","DD\\\\MMM\\\\YYYY HH:mm").toString()`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues here:

Firstly your date format using backslashes is causing a problem (single or double backslashes both cause different issues) in certain instances. I'm not sure exactly what the issue is, since the first example works, but I suspect it's treating it as some sort of escape sequence.

Secondly, "MM" is the wrong token to use to parse short month names. It should be "MMM". It seems coincidence that it works for your "Nov" string when using "MM", but it certainly doesn't work for "Oct" or most others.

If you can change your data source to provide dates using a different separator (`/` or `-` are pretty standard) then do that. If not, you might have to do a string replace on the date string just before you feed it to momentJS.

Examples of strings that don't work (either produce incorrect dates, or report "Invalid Date"):

```
"31\\Oct\\2016 22:14","DD\\MMM\\YYYY HH:mm"
"31\Oct\2016 22:14","DD\MMM\YYYY HH:mm"
"31/Oct/2016 22:14","DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
```

As you can see, it's evolved almost to the point of a parseable string, which would look like:

```
"31/Oct/2016 22:14","DD/MMM/YYYY HH:mm"
```

Comment: then I suggest you run a replace on the string to convert \\ to /. Out of interest, what datasource produced a hideous string like that?

Comment: moment("31\\Oct\\2016 22:14","DD\\\\MMM\\\\YYYY HH:mm").toString() works

Comment: 7 year old delivery till system for a fast food company, exports all the deliveries to a csv file, cant edit how the details are exported

Comment: yuk. I guess the \\\\ solution is easier than doing a replace then. Maybe @Andreas should post that as an answer.